# Qt | Is this possible to use declarative and quick modules simultaneously

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-quick, qtdeclarative

I have `Qt5` project that successfully compiled against `shared` Qt libraries, but I get a lot of errors (about 130 errors) like `* error: multiple definition of 'XXX'` when compile it against `static` Qt libraries:

```
/usr/local/Qt-5.3.0/lib/libQt5Quick.a(qquickanimation.o): In function `_q_interpolateShortestRotation(double&, double&, double)':
qquickanimation.cpp:(.text+0x330): multiple definition of `_q_interpolateShortestRotation(double&, double&, double)'
/usr/local/Qt-5.3.0/lib/libQt5Declarative.a(qdeclarativeanimation.o):qdeclarativeanimation.cpp:(.text+0xd80): first defined here
/usr/local/Qt-5.3.0/lib/libQt5Quick.a(qquickanimation.o): In function `_q_interpolateClockwiseRotation(double&, double&, double)':
qquickanimation.cpp:(.text+0x3c0): multiple definition of `_q_interpolateClockwiseRotation(double&, double&, double)'
/usr/local/Qt-5.3.0/lib/libQt5Declarative.a(qdeclarativeanimation.o):qdeclarativeanimation.cpp:(.text+0xe10): first defined here
```

Almost all multiple definitions detected in pairs:

- libQt5Declarative, libQt5Quick
- libQt5Declarative, libQt5Qml

<strike>I need to `libQt5Declarative` only for using `MessageDialog` in my qml</strike>

My `.pro` file:

```
QT       += quick declarative widgets network xml xmlpatterns multimedia

TARGET = MyApp
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += ...
HEADERS  += ...
OTHER_FILES += ...
RESOURCES += ...

CONFIG += static
```

My questions are:

- Why it successfully compiles against shared Qt, but fails when I compile against static Qt?
- Is this possible to use declarative and quick modules simultaneously?
- I compiled static Qt libraries by myself and maybe I done this incorrect, Is Qt have official static libraries package?

Comment: Do you mean the [MessageDialog from QtQuick](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html)?

Comment: You are right, actually `MessageDialog` belong to `libQ5Quick` but not `libQt5Declarative`. Post has been updated, but all my question still actual.

Comment: Thanks, @Oktalist, could you please write an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Qt Declarative is provided for Qt 4 compatibility](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmodules.html). I presume it is not designed to be linked against by new Qt 5 projects. It appears that it has been subsumed by Qt QML and Qt Quick.

Static libraries have no facility for specifying which of their symbols are exported and which are not, so identical private symbols defined in two different static libraries may conflict.